# Lookarounds and backreferences in WSDL restriction patterns

Tags: regex, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

In a WSDL file I would like to restrict one string value to a exact format. Therefore I created the regular expression

```
^([A-Za-z]{2})(-?)([A-Za-z0-9]{3})(?:\2)([A-Za-z0-9]{9})(?:(?:\2)([A-Za-z0-9]))?(?=$)
```

that matches for example the strings

```
DE-SLA-C12345678
DE-SLA-C12345678-8
DESLAC12345678
DESLAC123456788
```

To not match on sub parts of those strings and to allow the `-` only if specified on all two or three places, I am using the backreferences and the lookarounds.

The WSDL looks like

```
<s:simpleType name="name">
  <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:pattern value="^[A-Za-z]{2}\*?[A-Za-z0-9]{3}\*?[Ee][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\*]{0,30}(?=$)"></s:pattern>
  </s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```

However, importing the WSDL in SoapUI, I receive the error message **"Error: The regular expression '^([A-Za-z]{2})(-?)([A-Za-z0-9]{3})(?:\2)([A-Za-z0-9]{9})(?:(?:\2)([A-Za-z0-9]))?(?=$)' is malformed: This expression is not supported in the current option setting.  "**.

A regex fiddle to play around with the expression: http://www.rexfiddle.net/xZ1ToFp
What exactly is not allowed here? How can I work around this restriction?

Comment: The expression in your question and in the WSDL snippet are different?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have two similar expressions in the wsdl and confused them when copying in. Will correct this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html those lookarounds and backreferences are not allowed:

> "Particularly noteworthy is the complete absence of anchors like the
>   caret and dollar, word boundaries, and lookaround."

This means also that I can remove the anchors `^` and `$` as well.

My solution now consists of multiple restriction patterns with regular expressions allowing the various possible syntax. Those then act alternative *not* additive.

For example the following would allow `ABC` *or* `abc`.

```
<s:simpleType name="name">
  <s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:pattern value="[AZ]*"></s:pattern>
    <s:pattern value="[az]*"></s:pattern>
  </s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```